# BXSlider event when video starts playing

Tags: html5-video, bxslider

I am using BXSlider to display various videos.  I am trying to fade out an overlay when the first video starts playing.

I have tried hooking into onSliderLoad but that trigger before the video has started playing.

Anyone know if there is a way I can detect when the video has actually started playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the **[`playing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/playing)** event.

### Demo

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('vid');

vid.addEventListener('playing', function(e) {
  console.log('Video has started');
});
```

```html
<video id='vid' src='http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4' width='320' height='180' controls autoplay></video>
```